# ASP.NET MVC : Force ModelState and different ErrorMessage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this code :

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
[DisplayName("Password")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

I'd like, in some case, in my controller force the ModelState to false and show an error on the password field but with a different ErrorMessage

Is it possible ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this...

```
ModelState.AddModelError(string key, string errorMessage);
```

so in your case something like that.

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Password", "My fancy new message");
```

the key is the name of the property.

hope this helps